# unable to install curl-devel in red hat 9

Tags: linux, curl

I am using "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9.3 (Plow)"

When I run the C program, it give error of curl/curl.h: No such file or directory.

When I install `sudo yum install libcurl-devel`, it gives the below error message.

```
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9 for x86_64 - BaseOS (RPMs)                                                                                                                                                        115 kB/s | 4.1 kB     00:00
Red Hat Satellite Client 6 for RHEL 9 x86_64 (RPMs)                                                                                                                                                          108 kB/s | 3.8 kB     00:00
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs)                                                                                                                                                     132 kB/s | 4.5 kB     00:00
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9 for x86_64 - Supplementary (RPMs)                                                                                                                                                 108 kB/s | 3.7 kB     00:00
Red Hat Ansible Engine 2.9 RPMs for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server                                                                                                                                         15 MB/s | 1.7 MB     00:00
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server (RPMs)                                                                                                                                                                     326  B/s |  14  B     00:00
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'rhel-7-server-rpms':
  - Status code: 404 for https://hostname/pulp/content/MU/Library/content/dist/rhel/server/7/9/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml 
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'rhel-7-server-rpms': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```

May I know how to solve this issue?

I also tried refreshing metadata. But does not solve the issue.

```
sudo yum clean all
Updating subscription Management repositories.

sudo yum makecache
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 9                                                                                                                                                                         71 MB/s |  21 MB     00:00
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9 for x86_64 - BaseOS (RPMs)                                                                                                                                                         58 MB/s |  19 MB     00:00
Red Hat Satellite Client 6 for RHEL 9 x86_64 (RPMs)                                                                                                                                                          1.6 MB/s | 175 kB     00:00
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs)                                                                                                                                                      74 MB/s |  30 MB     00:00
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9 for x86_64 - Supplementary (RPMs)                                                                                                                                                  29 kB/s | 3.0 kB     00:00
Red Hat Ansible Engine 2.9 RPMs for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server                                                                                                                                         13 MB/s | 1.7 MB     00:00
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server (RPMs)                                                                                                                                                                     310  B/s |  14  B     00:00
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'rhel-7-server-rpms':
  - Status code: 404 for https://hostname/pulp/content/MU/Library/content/dist/rhel/server/7/9/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'rhel-7-server-rpms': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```